# Genuino 101 - Can't upload my sketch - Timeout Error

Tags: genuino, 101

I'm trying to run a sample sketch on my Genuino 101 but the following error shows up. Here is a verbose version.

```
Starting download script...
Args to shell: [/home/userk/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/arduino101load/1.6.9+1.28/x86/bin /tmp/buildc2bfbabdb2df5b87204fdf9941c899a2.tmp/Blink.ino.bin /dev/ttyACM0 verbose ATP1BLE000-1541C5635 141312]
Serial Port: /dev/ttyACM0
BIN FILE /tmp/buildc2bfbabdb2df5b87204fdf9941c899a2.tmp/Blink.ino.bin
Waiting for device...
Waiting for device...
Waiting for device...
Waiting for device...
Waiting for device...
Flashing is taking longer than expected
Try pressing MASTER_RESET button
Waiting for device...
Waiting for device...
Waiting for device...
Waiting for device...
Waiting for device...
ERROR: Timed out waiting for Arduino 101 on /dev/ttyACM0
```

I have installed the Intel Curie package with the Boards Manager and tried to press the Master Reset button, the reset and a combination of both. Nothing.

I have also tried the suggestions provided in this [question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18959/error-timed-out-waiting-for-arduino-101-anything-i-can-do) but they did not work. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Do you have any advice?

EDIT: Same problem with Windows 10/8/7.

Comment: did you try to use the reset button on the board??

Comment: yes, I tried but it did not work

Comment: check you COM and reboot your PC is needed

Comment: Same problem after reboot...

Comment: How u did the downgrade of Arduino 101 core? I am with the same problem and even the bootloader doesn't work...

Comment: Go to Sketch>Import Libraries -> Librariy manager > search for 101 > Select an older version and install it

Comment: Hi I understand now why there is a Timeout error... Read it here: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?action=profile;area=showposts;u=1472279 Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved with a downgrade of the Arduino 101 core. Try with all available versions.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Genuino 101 board been recognized by the OS? Sounds like your board is not being recognized by the system.

For windows, open up your device manager before plugging into the PC. After plugging in, the device manager should refresh and display the board in the COM Port section.

For Linux (in your case Ubuntu), you can use the *dmesg | tail* cmd to check whether your board is being detected when you plug in the Genuino 101 board.

Comment: Something is being recognized as /dev/ttyACM0 - question would be if that is the board, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem while uploading sketches , 
when i uploading the sketch and press  `MASTER_RESET` button solved my problem .
when it shows `Waiting for device...` just press the `MASTER_RESET` .

or try to update Firmware

```
Select Tools >> Programmer >> Arduino 101 Firmware Updater
Select Tools >> Burn Bootloader
```